# How do different data types depend on operating system in java?

Tags: java, types

I'm working with audio files in java (Assignment in my laboratory), and i read bytes from file then i convert them to primitive data types int and short. As i know primitive data types depend on compile settings and operating system. So how they depend on ? Are there immutable data types in java ? (i mean data types those don't depend on operating system and compile settings)

Comment: *"As i know primitive data types depend on compile settings and operating system"* - citation needed. Who said that and in what context? Are you sure you didn't read a text about C or C++ instead?

Comment: Or to put it differently, the official Java documentation disagrees with what you "know": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Immutable doesn't mean that, it means that once the instance is created its value doesn't change. For example, `String` is immutable in Java. There are certainly different audio file formats but one of the big advantages of Java is that its data types don't change across systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java primitives data types are not OS dependent.

These are the values for those types, and they are always the same.

| Type | Bytes | Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `byte` | 1 | -128 to 127 |
| `short` | 2 | -32,768 to 32,767 |
| `int` | 4 | -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 |

You can find out more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

How data is stored in files might be a different topic.

Answer (score 3):

All primitive types are fully defined in the Java Language Specification, which [writes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2):

> The *integral types* are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and `char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).
>
> The floating-point types are `float`, whose values exactly correspond to the 32-bit IEEE 754 binary32 floating-point numbers, and `double`, whose values exactly correspond to the 64-bit IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point numbers.

That is, there are no observable differences in behavior. Of course, the runtime is at liberty to use different representations for these datatypes, as long as it guarantees that behavior remains unchanged. For instance, a runtime may store a `byte` as 64 bit integer if it ensures that it behaves exactly like a `byte`, for instance by adding extra instructions that discard the upper 56 bits. Since such optimizations have no functional impact, and generally do not materially affect memory use, they are not usually worth thinking about.